# Include blade.php file in php file (with a booted Laravel instance)

Tags: php, laravel

Due to a very long lifetime of a system, I have a complicated setup, where part of the code is written in Laravel, and the other part is mostly in plain PHP.

Laravel is booted in the non-Laravel-part, so that I can use Laravel functions in plain php files. I can call  Laravel's helper functions and use other Laravel functionality in php files.

As we are slowly moving our non-Laravel-code to Laravel, I would like to include blade files in those plain php files. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: if your non-laravel? file is returned using view() then it will render any includes/require etc you have correctly

Comment: This also seems like it'll create more work for you, though

Comment: @Ballard thank you, seems to work, I added render-call on the view instance which is returned by the helper function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments, @Ballard suggested using Laravel's view helper.

Including blade files seems to work like this in php files:

```
echo view('partials.testblade', ['somevar' => "hello"])->render();
```